# UISearchBar with custom width disappears during UINavigationBar slide up animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchController with a UISearchBar at the top of my view controller view. The search bar sits above a UICollectionView and the whole setup is arranged through SnapKit.

```
    visualEffectView.addSubview(searchBar)
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal

    searchBar.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(topLayoutGuide.snp.bottom)
        make.leading.equalTo(visualEffectView.layoutMarginsGuide.snp.leading)
        make.trailing.equalTo(visualEffectView.layoutMarginsGuide.snp.trailing)
    }
```

This shows up as expected:

[image]

Trouble starts when the user taps on the search bar and the navigation bar is hidden pulling the search bar along with it:

[image]

So the search bar is not visible anymore. I am almost positive the issue is with the top constraint of the search bar being attached to the top layout guide, in turn being pulled up by the navigation bar sliding upwards. To that end, I have tried removing the constraint when the search bar editing begins but to no avail.

I have also tried adding the search bar as a header of the collection view below and that seems to work to a certain extent but it creates 2 problems: a) pulling to refresh shows the refresh control above the search bar and b) using sizeToFit on the search bar narrows its width by a few pixels misaligning it from the collection view.

How do you suggest I tackle this issue? Perhaps by intercepting the UINavigationBar animation and updating the search bar constraints? If yes, how would I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up abandoning this approach and placed the search bar on the navigation controller bar instead.

Before doing that, I placed both the search bar and collection view in a containing view hoping that the search controller animation will pull both upwards without making the search bar disappear. I also tried to place the search bar within a scroll view as the only solution that so far worked was with the search bar as a header of the collection view. None of the above solved the issue.

Still, I would be very interested in finding a solution to this problem if anyone else comes across it.